# How to remove the decimal string that returns in python when we use sum statement in sql?

Tags: python-3.x

```py
import mysql.connector

db = mysql.connector.connect(host = 'localhost',database='scores',user = 'root',password ='')
cursor =db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT SUM(game_rounds) AS sum_plays FROM game")
data = cursor.fetchall()

print('Total Game Plays : ',(data)

db.close()
```

This is the answer I get: `Total Game Plays :  (Decimal('2'),)`

I tried many ways to remove the decimal part but it wasn't successful.

Comment: have you tried `int(data)` or `float(data)`

Comment: yes I did. int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'. I get this error when I use int or float

Comment: you need to do `int(data[0])` as the second value in tuple is empty.

Comment: thats what I did. same error yet

Comment: I dont see why that would not work if your data is as you posted. What if you try `cursor.fetch()` instead of `cursor.fetchall()`

Comment: when i use only cursor.fetch() it gives the error "MySQLCursor' object has no attribute 'fetch'"

Comment: oh it is `fetchone()`

Comment: thanks ' fetchone() ' worked...  @Bjay Regmi